# No 'price_level' in Places Library detail search response?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The attribute 'price_level' is nowhere to be found in the documentation for the places library of JS API v3. See here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

However, it seems to be there in the REST API: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

I am building an Angular application where the price level is *crucial*. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[price_level is there](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult). You just aren't looking in the responses deeply enough.